# How do you build personas based on real users

Tags: user-research, personas

I've seen a lot of really 'pretty' personas online. but my question is how to build personas based on real users. how do you gather the info to create a persona? Is it from interviews, observations, surveys or usage data? and how to you translate this research into the personas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create user personas mainly using **user interviews and contextual inquiries**. If available, I will also use data from the analytics software to support my findings during the interviews.

The way I translate the research into personas is basically **looking for patterns**. I interview 25-30 people when I do a new round of user interviews and I look for similarities in their behaviours.

For example, if I am building an eLearning app and I ask the users about domain knowledge (how familiar they are with such activity) and most of them answer that they don't usually learn this way but they want to, then I add that in the user persona so everyone knows that the domain knowledge of most of our users is low. This will affect our design decisions when building the first prototype.

Comment: 25 - 30 people! That sounds like a lot, but may it isn't. Where do you find the people to interview? Do you incentivize them?

Comment: Here's the thing: After the first 12 users you start hearing the same things more and more often however every once in a while one user might give an insight or an answer that will give me more design ideas later on. I prefer to interview more in the beginning and then test with small groups (5 people) at a time. I use recruitment services, support tickets, social media, forums (depends on budget). Gift cards work best as a reward!

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the context!